# Multiple Select Query MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, join

I am new with php, mysql and everything that is the internet. I have an issue of which I suspect multiple selects may or may not solve. If you don't think this is the best way to do anything whether its table declaration or anything for that matter let me know, I have 3 tables.

---

### | HOTEL    |

- id
- hotel_title
- title
- City
- Country

---

### | Accomodation |

- id
- location_id
- title
- size
- en suite

---

### | Unavailable_dates |

- id
- accommodation_id
- start
- end

---

So as can be deduced several accommodations can be listed under a single hotel. E.g. Junior suite, Deluxe Room etc.
Each Accomodation also has dates in which it is unavailable. 
What I am trying to achieve is that when a user enters a date range for there stay so long as it matches **one** of the records in the "Unavailable_dates" of an particular accommodation it doesn't return that accommodation.

### For instance

### | Unavailable_dates |

```
|-id-| accommodation_id |    start   |    end    |
|-1--|-----2------------|--12/02/12--|-20/02/12--|
|-2--|-----2------------|--07/03/12--|-26/03/12--|
```

---

What I would like to achieve is that if my date is in the first recordes range but not the second then non will be returned as oposed to returning the second.
Below is some extra details that may help aid what i'm trying to get accross you don't have to read it unless you want extra details.

**Extra details**

```
SELECT location.*, accommodation.* 
    FROM location 
        JOIN (accomodation, Unavailable_dates) 
            ON (location.id = accommodation.location_id
                AND accommodation.id = unavailable_date.accommodation_id) 
    WHERE location.city='Birmingham' 
        AND 'check_in_date' NOT BETWEEN hotel_dates.start AND hotel_dates.end
        AND 'check_out_date' NOT BETWEEN hotel_dates.start AND hotel_dates.end
```

If my check_in_date is between the start and end date of the first record and my check_out_date is between my start and end date of the second record than no item is returned. Which is fine, however if my check in date is within the first records start and end date but my check out date is not between my second records it would return the accommodation as available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want a list of accomodations which are available. Now depending on the structure of data you have got i.e. Unavailable dates, it would be easier to find out unavailable accomodations by tweaking your query as below:

**Unavailable Accomodations**

```
SELECT DISTINCT accommodation.id 
FROM location 
    JOIN (accomodation, Unavailable_dates) 
        ON (location.id = accommodation.location_id
            AND accommodation.id = unavailable_date.accommodation_id) 
WHERE location.city='Birmingham' 
    AND ('check_in_date' BETWEEN hotel_dates.start AND hotel_dates.end
    OR 'check_out_date' BETWEEN hotel_dates.start AND hotel_dates.end)
```

Once you get a list of unavailable accommodations, its straight forward for get available ones:

**Available Accomodations**

```
SELECT location.*, accommodation.*  
FROM location  
JOIN (accomodation, Unavailable_dates)  
    ON (location.id = accommodation.location_id 
        AND accommodation.id = unavailable_date.accommodation_id)
        WHERE location.city='Birmingham' 
AND accomodation.id not in
(SELECT DISTINCT accommodation.id 
FROM location 
    JOIN (accomodation, Unavailable_dates) 
        ON (location.id = accommodation.location_id
            AND accommodation.id = unavailable_date.accommodation_id) 
WHERE location.city='Birmingham' 
    AND ('check_in_date' BETWEEN hotel_dates.start AND hotel_dates.end
    OR 'check_out_date' BETWEEN hotel_dates.start AND hotel_dates.end))
```

PS: Check the syntax and other conditions you may want to apply.

This query could be optimized further but the point I want to make is that you can make decisions based on the data available and then tweak it get get desired results.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Well in that case you can accept the answer. Happy it helped.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

```
SELECT location.*, accommodation.*  
FROM location  
    JOIN (accomodation, Unavailable_dates)  
        ON (location.id = accommodation.location_id 
            AND accommodation.id = unavailable_date.accommodation_id)  
WHERE location.city='Birmingham'  
    AND (('check_in_date' NOT BETWEEN hotel_dates.start AND hotel_dates.end)
    OR ('check_out_date' NOT BETWEEN hotel_dates.start AND hotel_dates.end))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response however it didn't quite work as I need it to, probably due to my pour description of the problem.Thanks non the less.